# How to clear old rectangle iterations in JavaScript based on my code

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, draw

I tried to look at other answers on here but my code is different so I don't know when to use clearRect(); to clear the old rectangles and give my code the illusion that squares are moving on my screen.

To give the readers a visual, I am trying to create my first Tower Defense game, so I'm wanting all enemies (squares) to move in a line but have a bit of spacing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tower Defense</title>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="600" style="background: url('pictures/map.png'); background-position:center; background-size:cover"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

    let ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

    let enemies = [];

    window.onload = function() {
        setInterval(showEnemies, 60);
    }


    //this function shows all enemies that spawn;
    function showEnemies() {
        let x = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            let mainEnemy = new Enemy(x+=25, 75, 20, "blue");
            enemies.push(mainEnemy);
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
            enemies[i].showEnemy();

            enemies[i].moveEnemy();
        }



    }

    function Enemy(x, y, size, color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.size = size;
        this.speedX = 1;
        this.speedY = 1;

        this.showEnemy = function() {

            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
        }

        this.moveEnemy = function() {
            this.x+=this.speedX;

        }
    }

</script>
```

If anyone can give me an explanation on where to put clearRect() I would greatly appriciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the canvas each frame before drawing your squares

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600); 
for (let i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    enemies[i].showEnemy();
    enemies[i].moveEnemy();
}
```

And i also suggest to move this part of code outside of showEnemies() function

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let mainEnemy = new Enemy(x+=25, 75, 20, "blue");
        enemies.push(mainEnemy);
    }
```

Comment: I tried that code but it didn't change anything. The squares are still just getting bigger and bigger and not resetting.

Comment: Maybe cause your are creating 10 new enemy each tick ?

Comment: Yeah I want to create new squares 25 pixels further every tick and erase the old ones.

Comment: 1. You are not erasing the old ones, and you are adding them to much in a quick time, So its look like squares are getting bigger (But they are not), try your code without adding each time new squares

Comment: I finally go it. I just simplified everything. I also see what you meant about separating creating the Enemy and moving them.
   
       let ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  
       let enemies = [];

       window.onload = function() {
              makeEnemies();
 }

 setInterval(function() {
  clearCanvas();
  showEnemies();
  moveEnemy();
 }, 30);